# ggplot2 add a guide for abbreviations

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following toy example

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df <- tribble(
    ~x,  ~y, ~name,            ~initials,
    0,   0,  "Hadley Wickam",    "HW",
    0,   1,  "Ross Ihaka",       "RI",
    1,   0,  "Robert Gentleman", "RG",
    1,   1,  "Yihui Xie",        "YX"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = initials)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text_repel()
```

It displays a set of points with labels, where labels are abbreviations of some specific values. What I want to do is to add a guide for the abbreviations similar to a usual point-shape guide, but with abbreviations instead of shapes.

So i want achieve something like this:

[image]
I know there is a solution for the case when all abbreviations are single-letter but unfortunately this is not my case.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the upcoming ggplot2 2.3.0, you can directly set up a scale and legend for the `label` aesthetic, avoiding the need for grid hacking or misappropriating unrelated aesthetics. However, I noticed that this works only with `geom_text()`, not with `geom_text_repel()`. I consider this a bug in ggrepel.

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~name,            ~initials,
  0,   0,  "Hadley Wickam",    "HW",
  0,   1,  "Ross Ihaka",       "RI",
  1,   0,  "Robert Gentleman", "RG",
  1,   1,  "Yihui Xie",        "YX"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = initials)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text() +
  scale_discrete_identity(
    aesthetics = "label",
    name = "Names",
    breaks = df$initials,
    labels = df$name,
    guide = "legend"
  ) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

The legend styling isn't great yet, but you can redefine the key drawing function to get pretty much anything you want:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~name,            ~initials,
  0,   0,  "Hadley Wickam",    "HW",
  0,   1,  "Ross Ihaka",       "RI",
  1,   0,  "Robert Gentleman", "RG",
  1,   1,  "Yihui Xie",        "YX"
)

# custom key drawing function
# modified from: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/22691ab1e14a9b615efb9f690d5dbaa599273496/R/legend-draw.r#L175
draw_key_text2 <- function(data, params, size) {
  grid::textGrob(
    data$label, 1., 0.5,
    hjust = 1, # right justified
    rot = data$angle,
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = scales::alpha(data$colour, data$alpha),
      fontfamily = data$family,
      fontface = data$fontface,
      fontsize = .8*11 # match font size to label font
    )
  )
}

# careful, the following code changes the legend for all geom_text() calls
# for the remainder of the R session.
# Undo via: GeomText$draw_key <- draw_key_text
GeomText$draw_key <- draw_key_text2 


ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = initials)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text() +
  scale_discrete_identity(
    aesthetics = "label",
    name = "Names",
    breaks = df$initials,
    labels = paste0("—  ", df$name),
    guide = "legend"
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.key = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5):

Not perfect, but may be a starting point. The point is to assign the `initials` and `name` pair to a meaningless `aes` (in this example `fill` is used, could be tricky in other situations), and then override the key representation in `scale_*()`.

Some more adjustment may be useful in the `theme`, particularly this takes up a lot of screen estate:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~y, ~name,            ~initials,
  0,   0,  "Hadley Wickam",    "HW",
  0,   1,  "Ross Ihaka",       "RI",
  1,   0,  "Robert Gentleman", "RG",
  1,   1,  "Yihui Xie",        "YX"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, 
               label = initials, 
               fill = paste(initials, name, sep = '\t-\t'))
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel() +
  scale_fill_discrete('Names', guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0), title.hjust = .5)) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! I've just added `label.position = "left"` to `guide_legend` and it worked perfectly for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack that requires some manual digging into the underlying grobs, but the basic idea is similar to @GGamba's approach:

**Step 1**. Create a ggplot object, with a shape legend based on the `name` variable. The corresponding geom layer is invisible (`alpha = 0`); it's just there for the legend.

(I traded `geom_text_repel` with `geom_text` here, as I think the issue can be generalised beyond the `ggrepel` package.)

```
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, label = initials, color = factor(y))) +
  geom_text() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = name), alpha = 0) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = sort(unique(df$initials)),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1,  
                                                              size = 5)))
```

[image: plot 1]

Here we observe that also `sort(unique(df$initials)) = c("HW", "RG", "RI", "YX")` are 2-letter strings, only the first letter is shown in the legend. Doesn't matter, we're going to change that anyway.

**Step 2**. Convert the ggplot object to a grob object, & check which grob corresponds to the correct legend.

```
gp <- ggplotGrob(p)

> gp$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[2]]
TableGrob (8 x 6) "layout": 14 grobs
    z     cells       name                               grob
1   1 (1-8,1-6) background rect[legend.background..rect.5267]
2   2 (2-2,2-5)      title        text[guide.title.text.5245]
3   3 (4-4,2-2) key-3-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.5255]
4   4 (4-4,2-2)  key-3-1-1           points[GRID.points.5256]
5   5 (5-5,2-2) key-4-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.5258]
6   6 (5-5,2-2)  key-4-1-1           points[GRID.points.5259]
7   7 (6-6,2-2) key-5-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.5261]
8   8 (6-6,2-2)  key-5-1-1           points[GRID.points.5262]
9   9 (7-7,2-2) key-6-1-bg        rect[legend.key..rect.5264]
10 10 (7-7,2-2)  key-6-1-1           points[GRID.points.5265]
11 11 (4-4,4-4)  label-3-3        text[guide.label.text.5247]
12 12 (5-5,4-4)  label-4-3        text[guide.label.text.5249]
13 13 (6-6,4-4)  label-5-3        text[guide.label.text.5251]
14 14 (7-7,4-4)  label-6-3        text[guide.label.text.5253]
```

In this case, the legends are in `gp$grobs[[15]]`, and the 2nd grob there (`gp$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[2]]`) corresponds to the shape legend. Examining this grob reveals that grobs 4, 6, 8, & 10 corresponds to the legend key contents for the four names.

**Step 3**. Replace the legend key grobs with the correct labels.

```
initials <- sort(unique(df$initials))

for(i in seq_along(initials)){
  gp$grobs[[15]]$grobs[[2]]$grobs[[2 + 2 * i]] <- 
    grid.text(label = initials[i], draw = FALSE)
}
```

**Step 4**. Check result.

```
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image: plot 2]

Comment: I like your solution because it's more safe in terms of text alignment while this can be a tricky thing for GGamba's solution (i will probably need to produce a lot of such plots and `\t` doesn't always give a good result). At the moment i would stick to the latter as it's obviously easier, but if alignment becomes a pain in the neck i know what to do then. Thanks!