# ggplot2: add 2 digits to legend symbol

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, symbols, digits

I've been trying to change the legend symbols of my plot. This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658977/change-the-symbol-in-a-legend-key-in-ggplot2) was really helpful, however I'm trying to create symbols that go from 1-33, and whenever I have 2 digits I get an error. Is there a way to adapt this code for this purpose? Here's a figure of my plot with labels from 1-9 then random letters just so it would show.

[image]

Here's my code (R v3.6.2, RStudio 1.2) for this plot:

```
ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = EV1, y = EV2, color = local)) +
  geom_point(size = 0, stroke = 0) +
  geom_text(check_overlap = F, aes(label = map_id, colour = local), show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5, shape = c(utf8ToInt("1"), utf8ToInt("2"), utf8ToInt("3"), utf8ToInt("4"), utf8ToInt("5"), utf8ToInt("6"), utf8ToInt("8"), utf8ToInt("9"), utf8ToInt("A"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"),utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"),utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"), utf8ToInt("K"), utf8ToInt("G"), utf8ToInt("F"))))) +
  labs(title = "Microsatellite data", x = "PC1 (14.6%)", y = "PC2 (10.0%)", color = "Locality") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Can you try something like`guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5, shape = c(1:33))))` or just `shape=33`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't really work. I've tried it and it actually gives me different shapes instead of numbers, and the default only has 25 different shapes, so some of them do not show up! :( Also, just a particular thing about my dataset is that I'm missing #7, so I have to skip that number too.

Comment: What's the error you get with double digits?

Comment: ```Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L,  : 
  replacement has 35 rows, data has 34```

I think it's considering as a new entry.

Comment: If I don't use the option ```utf8ToInt```, and just make a list of numbers, like this ```shape = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35")``` the error is different: ```Error: Can't find shape name: * '10'```

Comment: [This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/ggplot2-specs.html) says you can either do single characters or pre-existing shapes (unicode). 
So you could either change the key-glyph to a symbol or try the slightly hacky workaround from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273824/ggplot2-add-a-guide-for-abbreviations).

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I'm gonna try those solutions and see if they work for me!